# Error al Insertar múltiples órdenes en una sentencia preparada PHP - Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Estoy tratando de ejecutar varios UPDATE en una sóla sentencia de esta forma:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
    $sql = "";

    foreach ($data as $value) {
        if ($value->permitido == 1) {
            $sql .= " UPDATE rol_x_usuario SET rxu_permitido = TRUE WHERE rxu_rol = " . $value->id . "  AND rxu_usuario = '" . $user . "'; ";
        } else {
            $sql .= " UPDATE rol_x_usuario SET rxu_permitido = FALSE WHERE rxu_rol = " . $value->id . "  AND rxu_usuario = '" . $user . "'; ";
        }
    }

    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute();
    Database::disconnect();
    if (!$q) {
        echo "Ha ocurrido un error";
    } else {
        echo "La solicitud se envió exitosamente... ";
    }
```

Pero al ejecutar la sentencia obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: no se pueden insertar múltiples órdenes en una sentencia preparada in C:\xampp\htdocs\BERLINUXERP\model\usuario.php:189 Stack trace: #0
```

¿Habría manera de ejecutar varios UPDATE o INSERT en una sóla sentencia?
¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Tal y como te está avisando el mensaje de advertencia, no puedes ejecutar varias consultas preparadas (a veces es por no tener `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);`). Además, no estás usando correctamente las consultas preparadas. NO DEBERÍAS concatenar variables al SQL, debes asignarles marcadores.

Comment: mm porque no utilizas transacciones, inicias la transaccion y dentro agregas el foreach. al final le aplicas el commit, y como dice Oscar, utiliza marcadores, y no setes directamente en la sentencia sql

Comment: @OscarGarcia no se recomienda encender `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`, en ciertos escenarios se podría colar una inyección SQL emulada. Lo correcto aquí sería usar transacciones y/o  una consulta preparada usando marcadores, como se indica en la respuesta, donde los datos se asignan  dentro del bucle y luego se ejecuta al final.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo contigo. En ningún momento lo he recomendado (ni lo recomiendo tampoco), pero hay drivers que no soportan varias consultas a la vez y con dicha función podría ser que funcionará. Pero tampoco recomiendo es hacer varias consultas a la vez. Yo, personalmente, no he tenido nunca esa necesidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás desperdiciendo una potencialidad interesante de las consultas preparadas aparte de la seguridad. Además de que realmente tus consultas no son *preparadas*  en el sentido de que le pasas los datos directamente en la instrucción SQL, lo cual debe evitarse precisamente por motivos de seguridad.

Te muestro un código que hace lo siguiente:

- Escribe y prepara la consulta **una sola vez**, como debe ser.
- La consulta usará marcadores de `:nombre`, para luego poder pasarle los parámetros dentro del `foreach` por sus nombres.
- Dentro del `for` evaluamos lo que haya que evaluar, lo ponemos en un `$arrParams` y luego hacemos *binding* de cada dato a la consulta ya previamente preparada.
- Cuando esté todo listo, cada cosa en su sitio, entonces ejecutamos **una sola vez**.

Ganamos en rendimiento, en seguridad y en claridad del código.

Esta es la propuesta. Espero no haber cometido algún error. Debería funcionar.

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = " UPDATE rol_x_usuario SET rxu_permitido = :rxu_permitido WHERE rxu_rol = :rxu_rol  AND rxu_usuario = :rxu_usuario ";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);

foreach ($data as $value) {
    $status=( $value->permitido == 1 ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    $arrParams = array(':rxu_permitido' => $status, ':rxu_rol' => $value->id, ':rxu_usuario'=> $user);
    foreach ($arrParams as $k => &$v) {
        $q->bindParam($k, $v);
    }
}
$q->execute();
Database::disconnect();
$msg=(!$q) ? "Ha ocurrido un error" : "La solicitud se envió exitosamente... ";
echo $msg;
```

Comment: Lamentablemente no me funcionó, voy a tratar de arreglarla.

Comment: @DiegoMartinez intenta capturar el mensaje de error de PDO. Quizá es que no admite varias consultas fuera de transacciones. El código de todos modos está un punto de caramelo para transacciones (y sería lo correcto). Si te interesa podríamos intentar por esa vía.

Comment: Lo mas curioso es que no arroja error, dice que: La solicitud se envió exitosamente... pero cuando voy al PgAdmin los registros no cambiaron.

Comment: @DiegoMartinez Cambia esta línea así: `$msg=( !$q->execute() ) ? "Ha ocurrido un error: ".$pdo->errorInfo[2] : "La solicitud se envió exitosamente... ";` pero comenta esta línea de más arriba `//$q->execute();` para que no se ejecute dos veces.

Comment: aun sigue igual, dice que: La solicitud se envió exitosamente... pero los registros no cambian.

Comment: Ah, pasa `Database::disconnect();` al final también, debajo de `$msg`. Y si aún así dice que funciona, intenta el execute dentro del bucle, capturando el error en cada caso a ver qué pasa. Puedes hacer una prueba con `print_r($arrParams);` para comprobar que los datos están bien. Supongo que la conexión y todo eso es funcional **y que el `WHERE` del `UPDATE` se cumple**.

Comment: Pasa esto cuando coloco el el execute dentro del bucle:
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[08P01]: &lt;&lt;Unknown error&gt;&gt;: 7 ERROR: el mensaje de enlace (bind) entrega 1 parámetros, pero la sentencia preparada «pdo_stmt_00000001» requiere 3

Comment: ¿Podrías indicarme lo que arroja `print_r($arrParams);` dentro del bucle?. Parece que los datos no los está recibiendo bien.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88155/discussion-between-diego-martinez-and-a-cedano).